# Multiple occurrences error when trying to import JSON file with Mongoimport

Tags: json, mongodb, openshift, mongoimport

Im new with MongoDB and currently using Openshift infrastructure and following this tutorial

https://blog.openshift.com/spatial-mongodb-in-openshift-be-the-next-foursquare-part-1/

Im stuck at the part where I have to import the uploaded JSON file with Mongoimport. I have SSH in and run this command:

```
mongoimport -d parks -c parkpoints --type json --file app-   root/data/parkcoord.json  -h $OPENSHIFT_NOSQL_DB_HOST  -u admin -p $OPENSHIFT_NOSQL_DB_PASSWORD
```

and Im getting this error

```
ERROR: multiple_occurrences

Import CSV, TSV or JSON data into MongoDB.

When importing JSON documents, each document must be a separate line of    the input file.

Example:
  mongoimport --host myhost --db my_cms --collection docs <  mydocfile.json
```

there is only one JSON file in that ssh location though (Ive checked).

I found this issue being discussed here

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/cxVooO8DMJk

and it seems that using " " around the path worked for that person but it doesn't for me.

Any ideas whats wrong here?

thanks

Comment: The issue discussed in the link was resolved in earlier versions of mongodb https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7292.  I verified that I could import the file using mongoimport and think it might be an issue with the command you entered.  Did you try putting quotes around $OPENSHIFT_NOSQL_DB_PASSWORD?  What version of mongo is running?

Comment: I just tried putting quotes around that but still the same error, this is my version:  db version v3.2.3
git version: b326ba837cf6f49d65c2f85e1b70f6f31ece7937
allocator: system
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64

Comment: I found the answer in a comment for the tutorials video on YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1tc0tPY7oE&feature=youtu.be the final part of the command had to be this and not NOSQL as follows:                    -h $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST -u admin -p $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD